# Php date() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress as my cms..

i had need to schedule post programmatically every 60 seconds

This is the code i am using

```
 function techento_data_valid_schedule($data) {
  if ($data['post_type'] == 'post') {
    if ($data['post_status'] == 'publish') {
   // If post data is invalid then
   $time += 60;
   $data['post_status'] = 'future';
  $data['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
   $data->edit_date = true;

 }
 }
 return $data;
}

 add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'techento_data_valid_schedule', '99', 2 );
```

but when i publish the post...
it sets the date to jan 1. 1970 ?
Am unable to find the error in the codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting your `$time` value anywhere, so when you get to the line `$time += 60`, you're getting `$time = 0 + 60` which, in unixtime is Jan 1, 1970 at 00:01:00.

To correct this, you need to set your `$time` variable to whatever you need. If you want it to be the current time, try `$time = time();` and then add 60 seconds.

Comment: so what should i do to change it to 60 seconds?